# How to a object type data which contains a string of unique id for feeding in my model?

Tags: data-mining, dataset, data-cleaning

I am having a dataset in which data type of unique id of a user is in object form. I need to convert it into Int for feeding this data into my model.

here is first rows of my dataset.

```
event_id             event_time        user_ids       tag_from      tag_to
gse:161a4c6b24541287  2018-02-17 17:18:59   user_out_0  0
```

I am trying to convert my "event_id" column into a data type which can be used with ml models. here is the output of data.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1422907 entries, 0 to 1422906
Data columns (total 5 columns):
event_id      1422907 non-null object
event_time    1422907 non-null datetime64[ns]
user_ids      1422907 non-null object
tag_from      1422907 non-null uint8
tag_to        1422907 non-null uint8
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(2), uint8(2)
memory usage: 35.3+ MB}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the event_id will give any valuable information to your model? It is a unique identifier. What a model can learn from this? Please explain a little bit what exactly you try to do with the dataset since it might be possible that your data are not enough to train a model